# Discord.py bump reminder command

Tags: python, discord.py

i been trying to code a bump reminder / stopping disboard from processing a command in that period of time , and there is nothing that is similar to that i can find in the internet:
My current code is:

```
async def bump_reminder(ctx: discord.ext.commands.Context, action: str):
    disboard=ctx.guild.get_member(302050872383242240)
    if ctx.channel.id!=852646981759270972 :
        await ctx.send("Use this command at the bump channel")
        return
    if not action.casefold() == "bump":
        return
    if not disboard.status == discord.Status.online:
        await ctx.send(embed=(discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.red,description=(f"Whoa {disboard.mention} appears to be offline right now!\nI'll monitor the bump bot's status and notify everyone when it comes back online."))))
        return
    else :
        await ctx.send("thanks for bumping,disboard will be back in two hours to be bumped:)")
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(disboard, view_channel =False)
        lock_disboard_Out_for_two_hours.start()
        return
@tasks.loop(hours=2)
async def lock_disboard_Out_for_two_hours():
    guild =client.get_guild(844231449014960160)
    disband_role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="DISBOARD")
    bump_role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Bumpers")
    channel=guild.get_channel(852646981759270972)
    await channel.set_permissions(disband_role, view_channel = True)
    await channel.send(f"Discord is back, {bump_role.mention} come bump the server!")
    lock_disboard_Out_for_two_hours.cancel()
```

is there a better way of doing this or what do i do to make this work , as the loop task.loop() first runs , then wait 2 hours , then runs again, but i only wanted it to run after 2 hours, i hope there is a easy way of getting this command to work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read your question 4 times to understand it. Anyways, the [Discord Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.current_loop) say that you can access the current loop value (as an index, the first loop is 0, the second 1, the 10th loop is 9 etc.)

You can use it like this:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0, count=6)
async def slow_count(my_msg):
    current_loop = slow_count.current_loop
```

So you before sending all the messages you can check if `lock_disboard_Out_for_two_hours.current_loop` equals zero, meaning that is it is the very first iteration.

```
@tasks.loop(hours=2)
async def lock_disboard_Out_for_two_hours():
    if lock_disboard_Out_for_two_hours.current_loop == 0:
        return None
    guild =client.get_guild(844231449014960160)
    disband_role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="DISBOARD")
    bump_role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Bumpers")
    channel=guild.get_channel(852646981759270972)
    await channel.set_permissions(disband_role, view_channel = True)
    await channel.send(f"Discord is back, {bump_role.mention} come bump the server!")
    lock_disboard_Out_for_two_hours.cancel()
```